# Node.js pg-promise Azure function to write to Postgres (timescaleDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, azure

Azure is driving me mad again. What I try to achieve is that the data that comes in through an Event Hub needs to be written to the database. What I got working thus far is that the data arrives at the Event Hub and that the Azure function is able to post data to the database. I would prefer to do this with Node.JS as the integration seems kind of nice in Azure. The script I use to send some bogus data to the database is as follows:

```
module.exports = async function (context, eventHubMessages){
    const initOptions = {
        query(e) {context.log(e.query)},
        capSQL: true
        //capSQL: true // capitalize all generated SQL
    };
    const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
    const db = pgp({
                    host: '####',
                    user: '####',
                    password: '####',
                    database: 'iotdemo',
                    port: 5432,
                    ssl: true
                    });
    // our set of columns, to be created only once (statically), and then reused,
    // to let it cache up its formatting templates for high performance:
    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['customer', 'tag', 'value', 'period'], {table: 'testtable'});
    // generating a multi-row insert query:
    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(JSON.parse(eventHubMessages), cs);
    //=> INSERT INTO "tmp"("col_a","col_b") VALUES('a1','b1'),('a2','b2')
    // executing the query:
    db.none(query);
};
```

And yes, this is a snippet from somewhere else. The 'eventHubMessages' should contain the payload. A couple of issues that I have had thus far are:

- I can send a payload defined within the script or whilst giving it a testing payload, but I cant send the payload of the actual message
- pg-promise returns a 202 regardless of whether it fails or not, so debugging is 'blind' at the moment. Any tips on how to get proper logging would be much appreciated.
- I used 'capture events' in the event hub instance to capture the actual messages. These were stored in a blob storage. In noticed that the format is Avro. Do I need to peel away at that object to get to the actual array?

The input should look something like this:

```
[{"customer": duderino, "tag": nice_rug, "value": 10, "period": 163249839}]
```

I think I have 2 issues:

1. I dont know how to get meaningful logging out of the Azure function using Node.JS
2. Something is off about how my payload is coming in.

A more deeper question is, how do I know whether the Azure function is getting the data that it should. I know that the Event Grid gets the data, but there is no throughput. Namespaces are consistent and the Azure Function should be triggered by that namespace and get the input as a string.

I am seriously lost and out of my depth. Apart from the solution I would also appreciate feedback on my request. I am not a pro on StackOverflow and don't want to waste your time.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging I found a few things to resolve the issue. First of all, I was receiving the payload as a string, meaning that I needed it to parse first, before I could make it a callable object. In terms of code its simple, and part of the base functions of node.js

```
var parsed_payload = JSON.parse(payload_that_is_a_string);
```

Lastly, to get meaningful logging I found that the PG-Promise module has great support for that, and that this can be configured when loading the module itself. I was particularly interested in errors, so I enabled that option like so:

```
const initOptions = {
        query(e) {console.log(e.query)},
        capSQL: true,
        //capSQL: true // capitalize all generated SQL
        error: function (error, e) {
            if (e.cn) {
                // A connection-related error;
                // console.log("DC:", e.cn);
                // console.log("EVENT:", error.message);
            }
        }
    };
```

That then can be used as a settings object for loading PG-Promise:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
```

Thanks for considering my ask for help. I hope this proves useful for anyone out there!

Regards Pieter